# Flask-JWT generates error when Debug=False

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-restful, flask-jwt

I am playing around with Flask. I have created an API using Flask-Restful and Flask-JWT. 
 When `Debug=True` in Flask, and I do not send the Authorization Header, I get the response as [image]
 However, when the `debug=False`, the response returned is Internal Server Error with this stack trace,

```
[2017-01-19 19:43:10,753] ERROR in app: Exception on /api_0_1/deals [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ARFATS~1\Desktop\Dealflow\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ARFATS~1\Desktop\Dealflow\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\ARFATS~1\Desktop\Dealflow\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 477, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ARFATS~1\Desktop\Dealflow\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt\__init__.py", line 176, in decorator
    _jwt_required(realm or current_app.config['JWT_DEFAULT_REALM'])
  File "C:\Users\ARFATS~1\Desktop\Dealflow\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_jwt\__init__.py", line 155, in _jwt_required
    headers={'WWW-Authenticate': 'JWT realm="%s"' % realm})
JWTError: Authorization Required. Request does not contain an access token
```

I would like Flask-JWT to respond with the response which is there when Debug=True. However, I cannot use debug on Production servers. 
One way is to use my own jwt_required decorator. Is there any other way?
Also, I would be happy to know what I am missing, if any. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add this setting to your flask app:

```
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
```

When debug is true, PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS is also set to true by default.

Perhaps consider checking out flask-jwt-extended instead (https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended), it takes care of the PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS for you. It aims to replace the abandoned flask-jwt library, and add some conviences when working with JWTs (such as refresh tokens, easily adding custom data to the JWTs, fresh vs non-fresh tokens, and more). Full disclosure, I'm the author of that extension.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely check out Flask-JWT-extended.